# SVN Merge not finding my changes

Tags: svn, branch

Here is the command I'm issuing:

```
svn merge -r74:80 http://url.to/svn/branch/branch_name
```

It will think for a minute, then return a blank prompt like there's no differences between the two.
I know for a fact that there are differences between the branch and trunk.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command asks svn to merge the differences between revisions 74 and 80 inside the branch into your working copy. Does

```
svn diff -r74:80 http://url.to/svn/branch/branch_name
```

show any changes *to that branch* in these revisions?

---

Edit: `svn merge` gets two points in repository space-time, takes their difference and tries to merge that difference into your working copy. If you want to merge changes from trunk to a branch, you will need to check out that branch and make a merge à la

```
svn merge -r74:80 http://url.to/svn/trunk
```

or

```
svn merge http://url.to/svn/trunk http://url.to/svn/branch/branch_name .
```

while standing in that directory. Then, resolve conflicts, test(!) and `svn ci`.

Why does svn work this way? To give you a chance to resolve conflicts and test before you submit changes to the repository.

Comment: It does not. However if I do svn diff URL/to/trunk URL/to/branch it shows a bunch. Not sure what that means...

Comment: My trunk is updated to the latest revision, so is my branch. So, it's not like the trunk is out of sync with the repo... which is why I'm confused :(.